# What's the terminology for pressing down (inward) on a thumbstick?

Tags: controllers, terminology

On a controller that has thumbsticks, when it is possible to press down *into* the thumbstick - not D-pad down, as in UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT, but down on the Z-axis - what verbiage would one use to describe this?

[image]

<sup>Pictured above: Blue arrows indicate d-pad directions, and a green arrow indicates the inward down direction.</sup>

Saying "press down" could easily cause confusion with d-pad directional "down".

There must be some language used in the gaming world to express this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sony and Microsoft named the thumbstick click as a button itself:

- On PS they are commonly known as L3 and R3 (since L1 L2 and R1 R2 are on the back)
- On Xbox they are commonly known as LS and RS (left-stick and right-stick) or even LSB and RSB
- On Nintendo Switch, according to the mapping menu, they are just referred as "Left/Right Stick Press"

So "press the stick button" could be a good solution.

Comment: Has Nintendo given it a name for their JoyCon/Pro Controller? I'd be curious to see what they call theirs.

Comment: @scohe001 according to the mapping menu in the Nintendo Switch, they are just called "Left/Right Stick Press"

Comment: Steam deck uses the L3/R3 naming, too.

Comment: I distinctly remember the game Sly 2 on the Playstation 2 telling me to press "L3" and me having NO IDEA what I was supposed to do. I didn't even know pressing the stick had any meaning. Even more confusing, the Playstation 2 actually had analog buttons, which detected how hard you pressed them. Only a handful of games used such a feature, so most players didn't know about it, which made the games that *did* make use of it even more confusing.

Comment: Gamepad API calls them "Left stick pressed button" and "Right stick pressed button". https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/#remapping

Answer (score 54):

Another common term I've heard is [clicking](https://www.google.com/search?q=click+the+gamepad+stick) (in) the stick, which is less ambiguous than "pressing" or "pushing" with regards to moving the stick in a direction.

Comment: Steam notably uses this terminology when configuring controller button mappings.

Comment: I don't see "press" as an ambiguous term, since you also "press" a button.

Comment: @pinckerman Yeah, but you can "press" a stick in different directions. Pretty sure "click" is a standardized term to refer to what the question is asking.